# Getting undefined symbol: __asan_memset when trying to use Clang address sanitizer

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to use address sanitizer with clang to compile a C++ application but getting the following error:

> /Class.so: undefined symbol: __asan_memset

I have added -fsanitize=address to the compiler flags

> /opt/llvm-3.8.0/bin/clang++ -M --gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-5.2.0
>   -fsanitize=address

and I have added -fsanitize=address and -lasan to the linker flags:

> -fsanitize=address -lasan -shared -fuse-ld=gold-2.25  -o Class.so Class.o

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 12):

You main executable is probly not linked with `-fsanitize=address`. By default Clang links Asan runtime library (which provides definitions of `__asan_memset` and other Asan symbols) only to the executable, not shared libraries, and this causes errors in your case.

To work around this you can either relink executable with `-fsanitize=address` or relink sanitized shlibs with `-shared-libasan` and run with `LD_PRELOAD=$(clang -print-file-name=libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so)` (on other distros you may need to use `libclang_rt.asan.so`).

For more details see [AsanDSO wikipage](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAsDso#asan-and-ld_preload).

Comment: Do I need to put -lasan in the executable linker line?

Comment: @user997112 No, it has been discouraged by Asan devs e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/address-sanitizer/SD590XDinfQ/NMUPj_G0BgAJ). Linking with `-fsanitize=address` adds `-lasan` internally (in addition to other important stuff).

Comment: I have the same problem, but unfortunately, my main executable is called /usr/bin/python and I can't relink that :(   (a python module is loading the sanitized .so with ctypes.CDLL).

Comment: @Bulletmagnet In that case just be sure to compile/link sanitized shlibs with `-fsanitize=address -shared-libasan` and use `LD_PRELOAD=...`.

Comment: For me I had to use `clang -print-file-name=libclang_rt.asan.so` (without th `asan-x86_64`). I recommend running that command. You should get a *full path*. If not it isn't working.

Comment: @Timmmm which distro are you on?

Comment: RHEL 8. But I was using the latest binary Clang+LLVM download from the LLVM website.

Comment: @Timmmm Looks like the name depends on distro/toolchain vendor. I've updated the answer.